# HOw to onfigure Request payload in WSO2 APIM by Fast API

Tags: wso2, swagger, fastapi, gunicorn, wso2-api-manager

i am using Fast API endpoint like

```
@app.post("/get_question_answer/")
    async def generate_questions(email: str,request: Request, Usergpt_key: str = None,):

       text_data = await request.body()
       text_data1 = text_data.decode("utf-8")
       try:
       data_dict = json.loads(text_data1)
```

Now I am looking for configure this endpoint in WSO2 APIM so how I can configure this endpoint wso2 apim